# Show different form when clicking on different link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, drupal

I have a Drupal html like this:

```
<div class="field field-name-js-link field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">Enlace Responder</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="comments" class="comment-wrapper">
    <form class="comment-form ds-1col " action="/drupal7/felgtb-vih/httpdocs/comment/reply/39" method="post" **id="comment-form"** accept-charset="UTF-8" style="display: block;"><div><div class="ds-1col ds-form clearfix">

    </form>
</div>
<div class="field field-name-js-link field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">Enlace Responder</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="comments" class="comment-wrapper">
    <form class="comment-form ds-1col " action="/drupal7/felgtb-vih/httpdocs/comment/reply/39" method="post" id="comment-form--2" accept-charset="UTF-8" style="display: block;"><div><div class="ds-1col ds-form clearfix">

    </form>
</div>
<div class="field field-name-js-link field-type-ds field-label-hidden">
    <div class="field-items">
        <div class="field-item even">Enlace Responder</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="comments" class="comment-wrapper">
    <form class="comment-form ds-1col " action="/drupal7/felgtb-vih/httpdocs/comment/reply/39" method="post" id="comment-form--3" accept-charset="UTF-8" style="display: block;"><div><div class="ds-1col ds-form clearfix">

    </form>
</div>
```

I need that when I click on `<div>` with `class="field-name-js-link"`, the page shows a form related with this `<div>` (the form that appears below).
For example, if I click on first `<div>` with `class="field-name-js-link"`, it must show the first "form"; if I click on the second `<div>` with `class="field-name-js-link"`, it must show the second "form", etc.

All of this with javascript or jquery.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will make the comment field visible the first time you click, toggle it future times.

```
$(function () {
    $(".field-name-js-link").click(function () {
        var visible = $(this).next(".comment-wrapper").is(":visible");
        $(".comment-wrapper").hide(); // hide all the other forms
        $(this).next(".comment-wrapper").toggle(!visible); // toggle the form below this
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/HGS4W/6/)

Comment: Now, I would like to hide when I click again on the <div> with class="field-name-js-link".
I tried with a boolean variable, but it's not working at all. In this way, I have to click twice to get an answer.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the same. The div only shows the form when I click on it the second time.

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much, machine Barmar :D